# Is it reasonable to view each leaf node of a decision as a simple sub-model associated with a distinct class label?

Tags: machine-learning, cart

section 14.4 in [pattern recognition and machine learning (free)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) says

> There are various simple, but widely used, models that work by partitioning the
>   input space into cuboid regions, whose edges are aligned with the axes, and then
>   assigning a simple **model** (for example, a constant) to each region.

according to which, Figure 14.5 in that book

[image]

illustrates a decision tree consists of 5 simple sub-models corresponding to 5 distinct class labels?

is my understanding right?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the whole tree (or, in 14.5 the two dimensional space) is a model.

I'd say it's analogous to logistic regression. We call a logistic regression one model, not two (for binary logistic) or some higher number (for ordinal or multinomial logistic).

All the parts of the tree go together. Calling it one model seems to me to account for this.